# Excel VBA: Not able to paste text contain more than 32676 characters in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

i am creating am excel vba code that copy data from a page and paste is to excel sheet and i am copying innerHTML in my sheet that is needed.

So that innerHTML text contain characters more than 32676 that is limit of a character in a cell in excel.

Please help me solving this problem.

How can i divide that innerHTML text in my vba code and paste divided text in excel sheet???

or any other method to solve my problem, if you have any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using filesystemobject to read the data? If so then why not chunk the data into manageable lengths using a loop and the MID function. Then display each chunk on a different row in Excel. It would help if we could see what you have done so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all, got solution for this, i divided text  :)

```
a = Trim(Doc.getElementById("comparison").innerHTML)
a1 = Mid(a, 1, 32000)
a2 = Mid(a, 32000, 64000)
a3 = Mid(a, 64000, 96000)
a4 = Mid(a, 96000, 128000)
b = Len(a)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = a1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = a2
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = a3
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = a4
```